# What resources can I use to try and find out the name of the manager for a given fund?

Tags: mutual-funds, fund-manager

I'm looking to find out the name(s) of the fund manager(s) for a given fund - where can I go to find this information out? Are there any third-party sources for this info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yahoo Finance: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=VFINX+Profile

Under "Management Information"

Answer (score 4):

The fund prospectus is a good place to start.